# How to plot empty plot in R with xlab and ylab but without ylim and xlim?

Tags: r, plot

I found that `plot(0, type='n',xlab='...',ylab='...')` can give me an empty plot with labels. But when I add `lines()` later the plot is shown out of range of xlim and ylim. However, I cannot specify xlim and ylim in empty plot because them need to adapt to future lines functions. Is there any way to achieve this without using ggplot? Many thanks.

Comment: Why not just call `plot(x, y, type = "l")` if you want lines on a plot?

Comment: "*I cannot specify xlim and ylim in empty plot because them need to adapt to future lines functions*" - the base R plotting is essentially like a pen and paper. You can not change the limits of the axes on the fly to account for new data. Typically you would calculate the maximum size first and then add components later if you need that level of control.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I cannot draw lines because the plot is interactive in shiny and an empty plot is needed when there is no input. For the same reason, I cannot calculate the size in advance @thelatemail. I thought the limits of empty plot could adjust to added lines just like the limits of plotted plot() can adapt to lines

Comment: @DrX - I don't think that's possible. The typical way to expand an existing base `plot()` is really to regenerate it from scratch with new limits. You might need to use a different plotting engine altogether to make it truly interactive.